# getJSON in while loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, getjson, asynccallback

Hi i have a question i wrote a little barcode scanner

The app works like this.

1. first i get the order count from all orders with getJSON ordercount
2. Then i look into every order if the barcode exist or not with the while loop
3. If the barcode exist i run another function and put it into database.`if(myshopdata.order.reference==barcode)`

Now i want to run the function `no_code()` if no code match from the while loop and **geJSON finished** in function `get_shop_data`

Everytime i use the function i get the error message before getJson finished. But i want only error message if no code match.

Can anyone help me with my code how i can do it in my case?

In my Programm i call the first function with `get_order_count(barcode);`

```
function get_order_count(barcode) {
  //Get numbers of Orders
  $.getJSON("http://www.testurl.de/api/orders/?ws_key=TEEUQWTTU1J76LFQE&output_format=JSON", function(data) {
    // JSON Stringify;                          
    var order = JSON.stringify(data);
    var orderdata = JSON.parse(order);
    var ordercount = Object.keys(orderdata.orders).length
    get_shop_data(ordercount, barcode);
  }); //end of get json    
} //end of function

function get_shop_data(ordercount, barcode) {
  var orders = ordercount;
  var i = 1;
  while (i <= orders) {
    //Get Order Data
    $.getJSON("http://www.testurl.de/api/orders/" + i + "?ws_key=TEEUQWTTUJ76LFQE&output_format=JSON", function(data) {
      // JSON Stringify;
      var shopdata = JSON.stringify(data);
      //JSON PHARSE into Object                  
      var myshopdata = JSON.parse(shopdata);
      if (myshopdata.order.reference == barcode) {
        addcode(
          myshopdata.order.reference,
          myshopdata.order.associations.order_rows[0].product_name,
          myshopdata.order.total_paid_tax_incl,
          myshopdata.order.associations.order_rows[0].product_id
        );
        //vibrate if valid   
        navigator.notification.vibrate(4000);
      }
    }); //end of get json
    i++
  } //end of while
  no_code();
} //end of function

function no_code() {
  sweetAlert("code invalid", "Sorry", "error");
}
```

Comment: what is the exact error message that you get? please add it to your question.

Comment: `var shopdata = JSON.stringify(data); var myshopdata = JSON.parse(shopdata);` Why these two unnecessary operations? O.o

Comment: Not an answer but you could use a `for` loop instead of a `while`. `for (var i = 0; i <= orders; i++) { ... }`

Comment: I know there are some unnecessary operations i am learning java atm.

Comment: `var orders = ordercount;` also seems unnecessary, and I don't see where `no_code` is being called? I am guessing that you need to think about the async operation of your code. You should look into [`promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/

Comment: @Devil089 You mean Javascript. [Java and Javascript are completely different languages.](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_javascript.xml)

Comment: yes i know but how can i solve it ? I know that i can do it with ajax but its to slow. Normally i call no_code  after the while loop

Comment: Yes right sorry @ Mike

Comment: `$.getJSON` is sugared form of `ajax`. And if you must use jQuery then it has https://api.jquery.com/promise/

Comment: yes but is there are no solution for my code :(

Comment: Yes, writing some more code and using `promise`s or if you don't want to use them then you need to use callbacks (like done and fail etc, which are essentially promises) http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: Thanks for you your answer can you give me a example how i can use it in my code . That would be nice.

Comment: Do you intend for your `getJSON` requests to run in parallel or sequestially, is `no_code` supposed to fire upon the failure of any single request or only if all the requests fail?

Comment: I want to fire no_code if the while loop reach ordercount and no code was found. So if all requests fail.

Comment: I rarely use jQuery and any answer that I provide would be in pure js. In pure js I would be firing off my XHR requests with a Promise and then use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to to fire my function when they have all completed. I'm sure that there are plenty of jQuerians out there that could suggest the best way to do it with the jQuery API, but probably [`$.when`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)

Comment: Thanks for your help, perhaps anyone have a answer for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you are having is that you are writing synchronous code but the solution requires asynchronous thinking.

In pure Javascript.

Here is an example of what you are experiencing. `no_code` is executed before any data is received from your requests.

```js
function display(id, text) {
  document.getElementById(id).appendChild(document.createTextNode(text + '\n'));
}

function reply(fn, data) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    fn(data);
  }, 2000);
}

function getJSON(url, fn) {
  if (url === 'orders') {
    reply(fn, {
      orders: [1, 2]
    });
  } else if (url === 'order1') {
    reply(fn, {
      order: {
        reference: 123
      }
    });
  } else if (url === 'order2') {
    reply(fn, {
      order: {
        reference: 789
      }
    });
  }
}

function no_code() {
  alert("error");
}

function get_shop_data(ordercount, barcode) {
  var i = 1;
  while (i <= ordercount) {
    getJSON("order" + i, function(data) {
      display('got', JSON.stringify(data));
      if (data.order.reference === barcode) {
        display('match', JSON.stringify(data));
      }
    });
    i += 1;
  }
  no_code();
}

function get_order_count(barcode) {
  getJSON("orders", function(data) {
    var ordercount = Object.keys(data.orders).length;
    get_shop_data(ordercount, barcode);
  });
}

get_order_count(789);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/4.4.1/es5-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json3/3.3.2/json3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.34.0/es6-shim.js"></script>

<fieldset>
  <legend>Received</legend>
  <pre id="got"></pre>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Matched</legend>
  <pre id="match"></pre>
</fieldset>
```

The error is being alerted before you get a reply from the `getJSON` calls. The solution is to use `Promise`s, as per my comments.

Here is the same code, but now using promises.

```js
function display(id, text) {
  document.getElementById(id).appendChild(document.createTextNode(text + '\n'));
}

function reply(fn, data) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    fn(data);
  }, 2000);
}

function getJSON(url, fn) {
  if (url === 'orders') {
    reply(fn, {
      orders: [1, 2]
    });
  } else if (url === 'order1') {
    reply(fn, {
      order: {
        reference: 123
      }
    });
  } else if (url === 'order2') {
    reply(fn, {
      order: {
        reference: 789
      }
    });
  }
}

function no_code() {
  alert("error");
}

function get_shop_data(ordercount, barcode) {
  var requests = []
  var i = 1;
  while (i <= ordercount) {
    var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      getJSON("order" + i, function(data) {
        display('got', JSON.stringify(data));
        if (data.order.reference === barcode) {
          display('match', JSON.stringify(data));
        }
        resolve('success');
      });
    });
    requests.push(p);
    i += 1;
  }
  Promise.all(requests).then(no_code);
}

function get_order_count(barcode) {
  getJSON("orders", function(data) {
    var ordercount = Object.keys(data.orders).length;
    get_shop_data(ordercount, barcode);
  });
}

get_order_count(789);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/4.4.1/es5-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json3/3.3.2/json3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.34.0/es6-shim.js"></script>

<fieldset>
  <legend>Received</legend>
  <pre id="got"></pre>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Matched</legend>
  <pre id="match"></pre>
</fieldset>
```

Now `no_code` is executed after the requests have been resolved.

You want to use jQuery, so you will need to read their documentation and use their API, but the principle is the same.

Comment: I solved the problem to change the whole code :). My suggested way was not the best way to do it. No i use it without while loop